# How to automatically delete rows in Excel

Tags: excel

Consider the following (partial) Excel worksheet:

```
A  |   B         |  C    |  D
---+-------------+-------+-------
id |  date       | var_a | var_b
1  |  2011-03-12 | 200   | 34.22
1  |  2011-03-13 | 203   | 35.13
1  |  2011-03-14 | 205   | 34.14
1  |  2011-03-15 | 207   | 54.88
1  |  2011-03-16 | 208   | 12.01
1  |  2011-03-18 | 203   | 76.10
1  |  2011-03-19 | 210   | 14.86
1  |  2011-03-20 | 200   | 25.45
.  |  .          |  .    |  .
.  |  .          |  .    |  .
2  |  2011-03-12 | 200   | 34.22
2  |  2011-03-13 | 203   | 35.13
2  |  2011-03-14 | 205   | 34.14
2  |  2011-03-15 | 207   | 54.88
2  |  2011-03-16 | 208   | 12.01
2  |  2011-03-18 | 203   | 76.10
2  |  2011-03-19 | 210   | 14.86
2  |  2011-03-20 | 200   | 25.45
.  |  .          |  .    |  .
.  |  .          |  .    |  .
```

In reality, there are over 5.000 rows. I need to delete all rows which date falls on a saturday or sunday. In the example, March 12 and 13 `(2011-03-12/13)` and March 19 and 20 are Saturdays and Sundays. I cannot just delete every nth rows, since there might be days missing in the list (as is the case here with `2011-03-17`).

Is this possible to do with either a formula or VBScript? I have never written a VBScript macro before (I have never had a use for it) so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You didn't mention how automated you want this to be. You could add a column with the formula =WEEKDAY($B1,2) and then a filter on that column (6=Saturday, 7=Sunday) to interactively filter and then delete. Of course if you end up with a macro, WEEKDAY will still be key.

Comment: @JimO'Neil I have no preference on the way how this is done, apart from that I think it is probably best not having to use sort to delete the rows. I have updated the example; notice that in reality the worksheet contains paneldata. I have 100 companies (identified by `id`) and I have (the same) 500 dates for each company. I don't know If I will be able to get it sorted back to this after deleting the saturday and sunday rows...your insight please :-)

Comment: You're not sorting, you're filtering, the order will be retained.  If you add the column with the WEEKDAY formula, then turn on the filter to show only values of 6 and 7 you can delete those rows and the rest will be left (after you remove the filter).

Comment: @JimO'Neil: I just tried `=WEEKDAY($B2,2)` but I then get a message that there's an error in my formula. `=WEEKDAY(B2)` works, though. I now used Data > Filter, clicked the column header (`dayofweek`) and unchecked `6` and `7`. The rows then disappear (they are intrackted) but how do I delete them?

Comment: you'll want to leave 6 and 7 checked and uncheck the other five; then delete the 6s and 7s.   BUT double check the WEEKDAY return value, if you don't have the second argument, I believe Sunday = 1 and Saturday = 7, so you'd check 1 and 7 instead and delete those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do this once, this is what I would do.  This should preserve the order, but if you're really worried about it, read very end of the post:

1. Add a new column, call it "Is Weekend".  In it, put `=if(WEEKDAY(B2, 2) > 5, 1, 0)`.  Drag that formula down for the entire table.
2. Filter the columns.  To do that, select the entire table (click on any table cell then hit Ctrl-A), then

   - On Excel 2007+, go to Data-> click "Filter"
   - On Excel 2003, go to Data->Filter->Auto Filter.
3. Sort everything by last column (Is Weekend) in descending order.  This should put all weekend rows together without altering the order among the other rows.
4. Delete all rows with 1 in "Is Weeked" column.  Delete that column.

If you're really worried about preserving order, before you do the above, you can do the following:

1. Add a new column called "Position".  Put 1 in the first row, 2 in the second row, select them and drag it down to the bottom so every row has its own position number in increasing order.
2. Perform the filtering as above.
3. After you're done, sort everything in ascending order by "Position" column.

Comment: More complex than it needs to be.  The IF isn't really necessary, and you don't have to sort anything, just filter with the filter set to show the Sat/Sun rows, then delete.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that you don't need to delete those rows, you need to replace their values for C and D with 0. This is easiest done with IF() and WEEKDAY() within two new columns C' and D' referencing C and D. Feel free to then just delete C and D.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one go using an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx). In cell `E2`, enter the following formula (on one line), and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (as opposed to the regular <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$5000, SMALL(IF(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$5000,2)>5, "",
    ROW($B$2:$B$5000)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$5000))+1), ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1))
```

5000 indicates the number of rows in your spreadsheet. After this, the formula should have curly braces around it to indicate it is an array formula. `E2` should have the value `1`. Then select cell `E2` and drag the lower-right corner of the cell to the right until 4 cells are covered. Then drag the lower-right corner of the 4-cell-selection all the way down. At the bottom you will see rows containing `#NUM!`, one for each deleted row. You can delete those in the regular way.

In stead of starting off in cell `E2`, you could start off in cell `A2` of a new sheet. In that case, you need to prepend the original sheet name to each reference in the formula, as in `OriginalSheet!$A$2`

This formula is an adaption from the one given in [Excel: Remove blank cells](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/#array)

Answer (score 1):

In case you decide to delete the rows, please make sure to run the VBA code from the last row to the first row. Here is a piece of code just written from memory to show you the idea of running from bottom to the top.

```
For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WEEKDAY(Cells(r, 2),2) > 5 Then
        Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```